# RequireJS timeout loading main.js on slow connections using the optimizer

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm using requirejs to build my Backbone project. It's all working well and I'm able to use the optimizer to compile all the js modules and templates into a single main.js file. The problem is that main.js is about 1.5 meg. At work, this is fine as our internet connection is quick, but I'm noticing that with some slower connections, require.js times out before main.js is able to load.

Is there any way around this that doesn't make me alter the waitSeconds timeout?

For example is there a way to break up the main.js file into multiple pieces, or to force require to wait until there's an error produced when loading main.js?

Answer (score 4):

I think you dont need all the 1.5mb to show the user the inital app. So you can require some parts with conditions in your code. So instead of:

```
define(['module1','module2','module3','module4'], function(m1, m2, m3, m4){
   if(m1.someCondition){
    m2.start()
  }else{
    m3.start()  
  }
})
```

You can load parts of the app using `require`:

```
define(['module1'], function(m1){
  m1.start();
  if(m1.someCondition){
    var name = 'module2'
    m2 = require(name)
    m2.start()
  }else{
    var name = 'module3'
    m3 = require(name)  
    m3.start()  
  }
})
```

Note that the optimizer will only ignore the modules when the passed name is not a string

> From the docs:
>
> The optimizer will only combine modules that are specified in arrays
>   of string literals that are passed to top-level require and define
>   calls, or the require('name') string literal calls in a simplified
>   CommonJS wrapping. So, it will not find modules that are loaded via a
>   variable name:

```
var mods = someCondition ? ['a', 'b'] : ['c', 'd'];
> require(mods);
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm using the define sections as shown above. But the optimizer minifies all the modules and puts them together in a single js file. That's why the file is 1.5meg large. In my project, there are hundreds of small individual files.

Comment: Ok, the names have to be variables. Update my example.

Comment: But all the modules still need to be available post optimisation. My understanding was that the whole point of the optimiser was to collate the hundreds of individual files in to a small amount of files so that there aren't hundreds of ajax requests for files. My question is that this purpose sort of clashes with the waitSeconds timeout because slower connections won't be able to download the files in the required timeout period.

Comment: The idea is to split the app in larger components which consists of smaller requirejs modules. So lets say, you have an app with different section, create a entry point for every section, like you does it for your whole app at he moment. This section could be loaded when needed.

Comment: Sure. So how do I get the optimizer to do that?

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/requirejs/example-multipage. The trick is to add multiple modules to the build file.